# Display points on identical location from multiple layers with an offset

Tags: qgis, point, style, visualisation, vector-layer

I have several layers containging points holding information. Some of them are at the exact same locationg (as they originated from the same file, describing varous categories at the same location).

**In QGIS I would like the points from the exact same location to be rendered with a slight offset, so that one can see that there are several points at one location**. Quite similar to what could be achieved with the `Placement` option for labels for a single layer, or with the `Point Displacement` option for symbology, also just for a single layer.

Is there an easy option how this could be **achieved for a group of layers so that this offset is not just taking into acout points from a single layer, but from all layers?**

I have thought about the following options:

- Add small ofsets to their x/y location but this is impractical as it is not sensitive to zooming in/out.
- Merging the files in a single layer. However I would have to do quite complicated layer-styling then as each layer represents a different category (colour-coded) and quantity (size-coded).

**EDIT:** points from up to 10 layers can be located at anidentical location and none of them should overlap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using offset expressions. This will offset points in layer B with a random distance of +-300 m if there is a point in layer A within 10 m of it:

```
case 
when overlay_nearest(layer:='A', limit:=1, max_distance:=10) then array(rand(-300,300), rand(-300,300)) else array(0, 0) end
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @BERA, thanks a lot this looks almost exactly like what I was looking for! I should have been more precise though (and I'l edit my question above). There are up to 10 layer which can - in the most extreme case - contain points at the same loation. So I would need to offsett them all with regard to the other layers. The solution you proposed would still work but is a bit cumbersome, I assume.

Comment: Maybe you could merge all the layers to one and use that one as the "A" layer in the query